# Converting Oject to custom string format using Jackson Serializer

Tags: serialization, jackson

I would like to convert an object into a string representation which is like JSON without the fieldnames

for instance the following class

```
public class Employee{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private boolean married;
}

Employee = new objEmp();
objEmp.Name = "Mickey Mouse";
objEmp.age = 24;
objEmp.married = false;
```

the above object i would like to convert into string as 
    {"Mickey Mouse", 24, false}

and the array of this object must look like

```
[
   {"Mickey Mouse", 24, false}
  ,{"Robin Hood"  , 24, false}
]
```

I am looking for a solution that can be applied constantly for every java Objects (POJO).
so overriding toString() method of each object or solutions on the similar lines are not desired

I prefer it to do with jackson as i am all ready using it to convert Objects into JSON in Spring 3

I am looking for some jackson ObjectMapper configurations that can help me to achieve this 
or if not i can create my own Object Mapper and use it in Spring View

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ObjectMapper has the flexibility to do this, since what you are trying to generate is not actually JSON.

How about using reflection to get a list of the field values, and then serializing this as an Object array?

Something like:

```
List<Object> vals = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : Employee.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    vals.add(field.get(emp));
}
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(vals));
```

This gives you

```
["Mickey Mouse",24,false]
```

which has square brackets instead of curly braces. Is this good enough?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I wanted my objects in curly braces only but array of those must be in square braces.

however i can improvise the solution but can you suggest me how can i configure Spring 3 to use it as a View

Comment: I don't know much about Spring, but [in the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-json-mapping) it says "JSON mapping can be customized as needed through the use of Jackson's provided annotations. When further control is needed, a custom ObjectMapper can be injected through the ObjectMapper property for cases where custom JSON serializers/deserializers need to be provided for specific types." So maybe you should roll your own custom ObjectMapper subclass and inject that.